# How to aggregate information from indefinite number of groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, gini

How to aggregate information from indefinite number of groups in TSQL?
E.g. we have a table with 2 columns - clients and regions.

```
Clients Regions
client1 45
client1 45
client1 45
client1 45
client1 43
client1 42
client1 41
client2 45
client2 45
client3 43
client3 43
client3 41
client3 41
client3 41
client3 41
```

Every client can have any number of regions.

In the example below: client1 has 4 groups of regions, 2nd - 1 group, 3rd - 2 groups.

I want to count gini impurity for each client, i.e. to count - how different are the regions in client.

To do this, I want to apply to each client the following formula:

```
1 - ((% of region1 among all the regions in the client) ^ 2 + 
     (% of region2 among all the regions in the client) ^ 2 + 
   … (% of regionN among all the regions in the client) ^ 2)
```

But the quantity of regions is indefinite (may differ in each client).

This should be calculated:

```
client1 = 1 - ((4 / 7 ) ^ 2 + (1 / 7 ) ^ 2 + (1 / 7 ) ^ 2  + (1 / 7 ) ^ 2)
client2 = 1 - ((2 / 2 ) ^ 2)
client3 = 1 - ((2 / 6 ) ^ 2 +  (4 / 6 ) ^ 2)
```

This is the desirable output:

```
Clients Impurity
client1 61%
client2 0%
client3 44%
```

Would you prompt me the way to solve the problem.

Comment: Do this step by step. Write a query to get you the count per client. Write a query to get you the count per client and region. Join the two, so as to get percentages. Aggregate, so you can sum up the powers of percentages.

Comment: What is the expected output, based on the example data? Thanks.

Comment: added the expected output to the topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the formula could be expressed as a couple of group by:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Clients
         , CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(10, 0)) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY Clients) AS tmp
    FROM t
    GROUP BY Clients, Regions
)
SELECT Clients
     , 100 * (1 - SUM(tmp * tmp)) AS GI
FROM cte
GROUP BY Clients
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=56a56b77087efd3bac9ff10652e71148) seems to match expected output.

Comment: Syntax `1. *` count looks weird - didn't you mean to use minus?

Comment: No. `1.` will force casting of all `COUNT(*)` to DECIMAL. Otherwise 4 / 7 would be 0 instead of 0.57.

Comment: Surely using CAST on one of the operands makes for code that is more self documenting / maintainable..

Comment: Salman and everyone, who took part in discussion, thank you so much. Your code works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd approach this:

- in a sub-sub-query, do a `count(*) as cnt ... group by clients, regions`
- in a sub-query, do a `cast(cnt as float)/sum(cnt) over(partition by clients) as pcnt` and square it
- in the outer query do a `1 - sum(pcnt) ... group by clients`

There are ways to compact it to not use 2 subqueries but they might not make it more readable or easy to understand. I wasn't totally clear on whether you meant percent (out of 100) or ratio (out of 1) so you might have to add a `*100` at an appropriate point